# How to send POST requests in Dev Tools console (Google Chrome or Safari if can)

Tags: post, python-requests

[Example like the picture shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HuPZ.jpg)

How would you do this?, I searched everywhere but an example like this haven't been shown, it's probably something simple but I want to what they sent in the console for it too look like that, thank you